# Is there a source code available for patch command in Linux?

Tags: linux, patch, source-code

I am looking for a source code for the patch command used in Linux. Does anyone know if there is one available?

I am looking for a something which is compatible to POSIX or more specifically QNX v7.

Comment: There is source code available for pretty much *everything* related to Linux.

Comment: It turns out, from a hidden comment beneath one of the answers, that the questioner wants QNX, _not_ Linux.

Answer (score 4):

The default `patch` command on at least *Debian* (but presumably also on most other Linux distributions) is GNU `patch`.

The GNU `patch` project "homepage" is https://www.gnu.org/software/patch/

This page contains links to both [software repositories](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/tree/) and [downloadable distribution archives](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/patch/).

A Github mirror of the software repository is available at https://github.com/mirror/patch

BSD systems have an alternative implementation. The OpenBSD implementation may be viewed at https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/patch/

Answer (score 4):

There are several implementations of `patch` command in the wild,
`busybox` for example comes with its own. You're probably looking for
the source code of `patch` that your system comes with.  In order to
find the source code you have to know what you're looking for. You
need to check which package provides `patch` command and where the
upstream is.  You didn't specify what OS you use but on Debian you can
do:

```
root@64ee32ea5ee6:/# dpkg -S "$(command -v patch)"
patch: /usr/bin/patch
root@64ee32ea5ee6:/# dpkg -s patch
Package: patch
Status: install ok installed
Priority: standard
Section: vcs
Installed-Size: 238
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
Suggests: ed, diffutils-doc
Description: Apply a diff file to an original
 Patch will take a patch file containing any of the four forms
 of difference listing produced by the diff program and apply
 those differences to an original file, producing a patched
 version.
Homepage: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
```

And on Slackware for example:

```
$ grep $(sed 's,^/,,' <<< "$(command -v patch)" ) /var/log/packages/* | cut -d: -f1
/var/log/packages/metamail-2.7-x86_64-7
/var/log/packages/patch-2.7.6-x86_64-3
/var/log/packages/patchelf-0.10-x86_64-1
$ cat /var/log/packages/patch-2.7.6-x86_64-3
PACKAGE NAME:     patch-2.7.6-x86_64-3
COMPRESSED PACKAGE SIZE:     116K
UNCOMPRESSED PACKAGE SIZE:     290K
PACKAGE LOCATION: ./patch-2.7.6-x86_64-3.txz
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
patch: patch (apply a diff file to an original file or files)
patch:
patch: Patch is a utility used to apply diffs (or patches) to files, which
patch: are usually source code.
patch:
patch: Larry Wall wrote the original version of patch. Paul Eggert removed
patch: patch's arbitrary limits; added support for binary files, setting
patch: file times, and deleting files; and made it conform better to POSIX.
patch: Other  contributors include Wayne Davison, who added unidiff support,
patch: and David MacKenzie, who added configuration and backup support.
patch:
```

In both cases GNU patch is used and Debian package description even
contains a link to project's homepage
http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch but it's not working at the
moment.

It's also possible that you want to get source of `patch` you
currently use on your system with all patches and comments added by
package maintainers.  On Debian you can do:

```
$ apt-get source patch
```

Comment: Note that the savanna link point to the GNU variant. There are other implementations, all based on the last version from Larry Wall. BTW: The other versions are superior to the GNU variant.

Comment: I thought that I've stressed it clearly said that both Debian and Slackware use GNU patch and  that plenty of other implementations exist. Isn't this clear enough?

Comment: Since this user explicitly asked for the source, he might be interested in a better source as well...

Comment: Disclaimer: Jörg Schilling (@schily) is the author of a suite of Unix utilities, which include an alternate implementation of the `patch` command, hence his interest in pointing people at alternatives to GNU patch.

Comment: @larsks yes, I know that. I just think I did my best to emphasize that other implentations of `patch` exist and described how to find out which version of `patch` is available on the system. I really cannot see what else can I say. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I think you did a great job! I just think that @schily should disclose his interest in alternatives .

Comment: @larsks while I never hide my interests (and I cannot, since I am well known), I usually add hints like the one above if I see a biased answer. This answer e.g. contains vendor Debian specific advertising as the question did not ask for a Debian specific answer.

Comment: @schily: I said that I don't know what OS OP uses so I gave two examples - Debian and Slackware. I'm not *advertising* anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info guys! I was looking for a something which is compatible to POSIX or more specifically QNX v7. I will look into the ones based on GNU that should probably work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, you most likely use GNU patch, see http://www.gnu.org, but `patch` has a long history and exists in more than just one variant:

`patch` is a program originally written by Larry wall in May 1985.
[He posted the source for version 1.3 in shar format to Usenet newsgroup `mod.sources`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mod.sources/xSQM63e39YY/apNNJSkJi0gJ).

Version 2.0 was published in 1986 by Larry Wall by a post to `comp.sources.unix` (as `mod.sources` was later renamed) and the latest version from Larry Wall was made in June 1988.

The original license from Larry was:

```
* This program may be copied as long as you don't try to make any
* money off of it, or pretend that you wrote it.
```

which is not aligned with today's ideas of OSS since it forbids to "make money" off it.

Since a program as complex as `patch` needs attention, there are several derived versions.

The GNU people came up with a GPLd version in 1990, but AFAIK did never verify that Larry did give his OK for this license change.

A closed source version from IBM, HP, DEC and Sun has been made in the 1990s. It has been made POSIX compliant but did never fix all known bugs.

Approx. 10 years ago, variants without GPLd code have been created by OpenBSD and by me.

Approx. 5 years ago, Larry did give permission to the OpenBSD people and to me to use the 1 clause BSD license in order to make patch OSS compliant.

While there is some kind of exchange between the BSD people and me regarding bugs and security problems, the GNU version is separate.

The version in `schilytools` includes an expensive test suite for patch and compares the results with expected results and with the results from the locally installed version. Since this is (in many cases gpatch), it needs to include some workarounds every time it detects a bug in the system installed version ,-)

The man page for the schilytools version can be found here: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/patch.1.html

Given that the OP is interested in QNX, the OpenBSD source is not of interest to him since that source is not portable. The schilytools are highly portable even though it is a longer time since the last feedback to a QNX compilation has been seen. So if it does not compile anymore on QNX, send a hint.

BTW: GNU patch is in conflict with some of the requirements from POSIX.

Comment: Now that we know that the questioner wants this for QNX, you might like to add that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding QNX